# Render object in Django that have Status = Accept or Reject separately in a specific template

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django. I am working on a project where if client click on a "accept or reject" button then that object will also appears in their respective templates. For example if a client click on accept button then that object will be appear in accept .html file and the same will be work with reject button.I have no idea how can I do this.

this is my accept .html file:

```
<div class="body table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S No.</th>
                <th>COMPANY NAME</th>
                <th>TEAM MEMBER</th>
                <th>EMAIL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                {%for team in object%}
            <tr>

                <th scope="row"> {{ forloop.counter }}</th>
                <td>{{team.company_name}}</td>
                <td>{{team.team_member}}</td>
                <td>{{team.email}}</td> 
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

here it is rendering all the objects that are in database but i want that only those object are displayed here which have Status = "accept" and the same should be work with reject status.

here is my model.py

```
first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
address = models.CharField(max_length= 1000)
state = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
city = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
pin_code = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
status = models.CharField(max_length= 30)
```

here is my views.py

```
def accept(request):
   obj= Create_Team.objects.all()
   return render(request, "admin/accept.html", {"object": obj})
```

and the same is my reject views.

I want that when ever the client clicks the accept or reject button then that object or objects will display in their respective pages. Or in simple words i want to render the objects to accept page whose Status is equal to accept and same will be done with reject. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are having trouble. If you just want to show objects with a certain status, then you need to filter them in your view:

```
obj = Create_Team.objects.filter(status='accepted') # or whatever the value is
```

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want and it works for me